# how to include PyOpenSSL in a python package

Tags: python, openssl, package, pyopenssl

I need to deploy an application on AWS Lambda in python .
This app is based on Google API SDK, which require a crypto library such as pyOpenSSL. 
But, contrary to other libs which are included in my package by doing something like this :

```
pip install myLib -t \my_path\to_my_package\
```

, the pyOpenSSL seems to be a part of python. It's implemented while compiling or via

`apt-get install pyopenssl`.

I have no clue on what to do to import this lib without depending on the python version and its modules.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never have used AWS Lambda, but I have been using `pip install requests[security]` to install security packages. It also includes `pyopenssl`. You might want to try it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Having this same issue. I have been getting an error `CryptoUnavailableError` when using `pyopenssl` with `oauth2client`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to install the package "Crypto" in my package and make a :

```
import Crypto
```

That solved the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "make a !"?  I am having a similar issue